# Missing values when using dict.append() in Python

Tags: python

there is something wrong when I use dict.append(values) but not all of values are added

```
list1 = {1:{0:{'S':-0.5, 'L':0.5}, 5:{3:{'S':2, 'L':4}, 6:{'S':5.5, 6.5:{'S':6.25, 'L':6.75}}}}} 

def getNum(list2):
    anArray = [] 
    for key in list2:
        if type(key).__name__ == 'str':
            print(list2[key])
            anArray.append(list2[key])
        if type(list2[key]).__name__ == 'dict':
            anArray = getNum(list2[key])
            if type(key).__name__ == 'int':
                anArray.append(key)
                print(key)
    return anArray
```

The result is:

```
>>> a = pra1.getNum(pra1.list1)
0.5
-0.5
0
4
2
3
6.75
6.25
5.5
6
5
1
>>> a
[6.75, 6.25, 5.5, 6, 5, 1]
```

Why the result for append command does not include all number in my dict?

Comment: Where do you use `dict.append()`? There is no `append()` method on python `dict`s. You are `append`-ing your numbers to a `list` that you call `anArray`. Make sure you have your concepts and naming right, otherwise it is difficult to discuss, or think about, what you are doing.

Comment: You should also try and follow [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: thanks for your advice

Answer (score 3):

There's no `dict.append()`, but you are using [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). The problem is that you have

```
        if type(list2[key]).__name__ == 'dict':
            anArray = getNum(list2[key])
```

instead of

```
        if type(list2[key]).__name__ == 'dict':
            anArray.extend(getNum(list2[key]))
```

in your recursive function, so you overwrite the collected values with a new list every time you find a nested dict. Using [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) you append all the items found in the recursive call to your list.

Consider using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
        if isinstance(list2[key], dict):
```

etc. instead of checking the type name.